# Can always login

Tags: iphone, authentication, afnetworking

A colleague and me have stumbled upon bug in both of our codes. We happen to both be working on a login page. I am using the networking library AFNetworking to connect to an outside source, which tells if the user has actually registered. The friend likewise (but without any outside library). (Code is for ios.)

We are both running into the same problem: after making a valid call, everything goes as expected. But if we make another call that is invalid (e.g., wrong username and/or password) I am still able to login.

Why? We are not saving any information.

Here is some code:

```
  BasicAuth * manger  =  [BasicAuth sharedManager];
  manger = nil;
  [[BasicAuth sharedManager] setUsername:@"bad_username" andPassword:@"wrong"];

   [[BasicAuth sharedManager]  getPath:@"/users/tokens"
                          parameters:nil
                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                 NSLog(@"operation = %@", [responseObject description]);
                                 NSError *error = nil;
                                 /*
                                  */
                                 if (error) {
                                     NSLog(@"Error serializing %@", error);
                                 }


                             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                 if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {

                                 } else {
                                     NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                //     NSString *errorMessage = [ objectForKey:@"error"];

                                     NSLog(@"We have an issue %@", [error description]);

                                 }
                             }];    return YES;
```

If I call this same code but with a correct username/password AND THEN call the above code, then I can still login in and the information I get back is the same as when I sent the "good" request. Also, when I try to make login requests using curl from my laptop I do not run into the same issues, which is making me think that, for some reason, the information being sent is not being updated. But I can't see how or why. Again, this is whether 3rd party library is being used or not.

Thoughts, suggestions?

note: BasicAuth (see above) is a subclass of AFHTTPCLIENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server may be sending some cookie and iOS is store it.
Try to delete the cookies before setting the new username and password.
Here you have a code snippet that deletes all cookies. Keep in mind that in iOS the cookies are application private, so deleting them is not going to affect other apps.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [storage cookies];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
{
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```